# How to get mysql view definitions?

Tags: mysql, view

`Show create view viewName` does not display correctly formatted text. How can I get the correctly-formatted SQL?

For example, I created a view like `create view v1 as select * from mysql.uer`, but it return like this:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW v1 AS 
    select 
        mysql.user.Host AS Host,
        mysql.user.User AS User,
        mysql.user.Password AS Password,
        mysql.user.Select_priv AS Select_priv,
        ... ..., 
        mysql.user.Grant_priv AS Grant_priv,
        mysql.user.References_priv AS References_priv,
        mysql.user.Index_priv AS Index_priv,
        mysql.user.Alter_priv AS Alter_priv
    from mysql.user
```

How can I get my original definitions?

Comment: So, it correctly returns the SQL. Where is the problem? You will not get back exactly the `select * from mysql.user` because the `*` is expanded when the view is created.

Comment: Original definition is gone.  "Live with it".

Comment: phpMyAdmin can get the original definition, I hope I could do same thing. In fact, I found that v1.frm contains the original definition. But in centOS 6.5, I can't use "load_file" to read the v1.frm, it return null.

Answer (score 14):

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW viewName
```

returns the SQL definition with a `CREATE VIEW` statement.

---

```
SELECT  VIEW_DEFINITION 
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA    = 'DATABASENAME' 
    AND     TABLE_NAME      = 'VIEWNAME';
```

returns only definition.

Both are correct for getting view definition.

Comment: So what does this add to the question and another already existing answer?

Comment: @dezso it adds another command, with a different output. Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli to my untrained eyes the result is a subset (albeit schema qualified) of the already mentioned one, and it does not bring the OP closer to what they want.

Comment: @dezso I want to clear difference between these two query.

Comment: I believe that the best choice depends on what will process this output: a human or a program? The question doesn't specify this, so showing both options is nice.

Comment: The select from information schema saved my ass. I had views with COLLATE's inside. Someone changed collations in the DB and the views stopped working because of collation errors. SHOW CREATE VIEW also returned collate errors  instead of the definition...